# Aviary SDK android crash on startActivityForResult

Tags: android, aviary

I have integrated Aviary SDK for photo editing in my application. But when i start intent for result, application just crashed every time.
Please provide any solution.

Following is the code.

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(thisContext, FeatherActivity.class );
newIntent.setData( Uri.parse(image_path));
newIntent.putExtra( Constants.EXTRA_IN_API_KEY_SECRET, api_secret_key );
startActivityForResult( newIntent, 1 );


11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fourspan.ecoviate/com.aviary.android.feather.FeatherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at com.aviary.android.feather.FeatherActivity.onContentChanged(FeatherActivity.java:916)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at com.aviary.android.feather.FeatherActivity.onCreate(FeatherActivity.java:556)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
11-10 18:01:05.681: E/AndroidRuntime(18797):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
```

Thanks

Comment: Same issue, did you find the problem?

Comment: Yes! nothing wrong with the code. I just followed the sample app provided in Aviary documentation and find out the problem was in manifest. Please replace aviary code in manifest with one provided in sample app. I think there is some thing missing in Aviary documentation.